# Is discord compatible with Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: updates, 21.10

Whenever I try updating to ubuntu 21.10, the updater says it will uninstall discord. Has anyone else had this problem, and is there a solution, or am I stuck on 21.04 until this issue gets fixed?

EDIT: reinstalling discord isn't a problem, I'm just concerned it might be uninstalling due to being incompatible with 21.10, although I could be wrong?

EDIT 2: I solved the problem by installing discord through the software center (you could also use https://snapcraft.io/discord or `sudo snap install discord` to install it)

Comment: Just let is uninstall it then you can install it again and log into your ID to get the chats and servers back

Comment: @Algnis Will it let me install discord in 21.10? There clearly is a reason it gets uninstalled, and my assumption is that discord is incompatible with 21.10, although I could be very wrong?

Comment: As being a 21.10 user I can confirm discord works on my pc and there was no issue while installing , so it maybe a bug in some systems

Comment: @Algnis Strange. Are you using the .deb version of discord or the snap version?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 21.10, and the Discord package from the Software app works fine for me

Comment: Thanks @cocomac, I will try that now :)

Comment: I use the snap version of discord

Comment: Update: Cocomac's solution worked. Thanks Algnis for the extra help. I hope you both have a great day